# Custom Toggleswitch with binding to object

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am trying to create a toggleswitch which will have multiple rows in the datatemplate bound to different properties of a single object. These toggleswitches will be inside a listbox.

My xaml code below shows the current toggleswitch template. With the code below, only the header is binding properly. I need the other two rows (in the ContentTemplate) and the toggleswitch itself to bind to a boolean property of the object.

```
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="{Binding Property1}" Width="450">
                                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ContentControl FontWeight="Black" FontSize="40" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.HeaderTemplate>
                                <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property2}" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Light"  Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property3}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
                            </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

Any advice here on how to achieve the results I need?

Thanks in advance!

Here is what I am trying to achieve

```
Property1 
Property2:On/Off                  [===]    (this is the toggle switch)
Property3
```

Properties 1,2, and 3 all will have custom formatting as well. Please keep in mind these will be in a listbox, so they will be binding to a collection.

Comment: Can you please show a mocked up image to show what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I added a sort of mockup to show you what I would like the user to see. Thanks!

Comment: how does the "On"/"Off" label fit in with your mock-up?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that, I would like that to fall on the second line directly after Propery2. I will edit the mockup to reflect this. What I am looking for is not much different than the toggleswitch found in the native Alarm app found on the phone. I would just like the second and third textblocks to be properly bound to the same object as the header.

Comment: @andersra Did you get this working? I'm also looking for a similar solution. if you can share your code on how you were able to data bind the 2nd and 3rd text blocks, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify the source of the ToggleSwitch in the converter.

Add extra text/string properties to have something to bind Property2 and Property3 to. (These will also need to be separate items to be templated differently- like in the alarms app.)

Then look at changing the binding for the `ContentProperty` or extend the OffOnConverter to include the additional new proprties.

Comment: Where is the converter you are referring to? My header binds properly, so I am not sure why the other textblocks in the content section do not bind the same way.

Comment: @andersra it's in the source of the toggleswitch

Comment: By source, do you mean source code from toolkit in the codeplex?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you need is binding to an element, check this post:

[Silverlight 3 Element binding in a datatemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957389/silverlight-3-element-binding-in-a-datatemplate)

Give the element with data template x:Name property and then use element binding from within data template.

Hope this helps,
Robert

Comment: This is not what I am looking for